# Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ - RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java, data-class

I am calling an API using RxJava and Retrofit and storing the data in data class of kotlin. While calling the api, an error is thrown : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $.

Here is the code:

**API JSON:**

```
{
    "facilities": [
        {
            "facility_id": "1",
            "name": "Property Type",
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Apartment",
                    "icon": "apartment",
                    "id": "1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Condo",
                    "icon": "condo",
                    "id": "2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Boat House",
                    "icon": "boat",
                    "id": "3"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Land",
                    "icon": "land",
                    "id": "4"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "facility_id": "2",
            "name": "Number of Rooms",
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "1 to 3 Rooms",
                    "icon": "rooms",
                    "id": "6"
                },
                {
                    "name": "No Rooms",
                    "icon": "no-room",
                    "id": "7"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "facility_id": "3",
            "name": "Other facilities",
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Swimming Pool",
                    "icon": "swimming",
                    "id": "10"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Garden Area",
                    "icon": "garden",
                    "id": "11"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Garage",
                    "icon": "garage",
                    "id": "12"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "exclusions": [
        [
            {
                "facility_id": "1",
                "options_id": "4"
            },
            {
                "facility_id": "2",
                "options_id": "6"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "facility_id": "1",
                "options_id": "3"
            },
            {
                "facility_id": "3",
                "options_id": "12"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "facility_id": "2",
                "options_id": "7"
            },
            {
                "facility_id": "3",
                "options_id": "12"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

**The data class for serialization:**: (FacilitiesData.kt)

```
data class Facilities(
    @SerializedName("facilities")
    val facilities: List<Facility>
)

data class Facility(
    @SerializedName("facility_id")
    val facility_id: String?,
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String?,
    @SerializedName("options")
    val options: List<Options>
)

data class Options(
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String?,
    @SerializedName("icon")
    val icon: String?,
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: String?
)
```

**RxJava code to fetch the response:**

```
  private fun fetchFacilities() {
        loading.value = true
        disposable.add(
            facilityService.getFacilities()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(object: DisposableSingleObserver<List<Facilities>>() {
                    override fun onSuccess(value: List<Facilities>?) {
                        facilities.value = value
                        loadError.value = false
                        loading.value = false
                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Throwable?) {
                        Log.e("Error", e.toString())
                        loadError.value = true
                        loading.value = false
                    }

                })
        )
    }
```

**The interface to fetch the api:** (FacilityApi)

```
interface FacilityApi {

    @GET("/iranjith4/ad-assignment/db")
    fun getFacilities() : Single<List<Facilities>>
}
```

**Service class to call the service api** (FacilityService)

```
class FacilityService {

    @Inject
    lateinit var api: FacilityApi

    init {
        DaggerApiComponent.create().inject(this)
    }

    fun getFacilities(): Single<List<Facilities>> {
        return api.getFacilities()
    }
}
```

What can be the possible reason for the error? Please let me know.

Comment: I think you want `fun getFacilities() : Single<Facilities>`. Your Facilities class is the root.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you are showing is an Object defined by the `{` that contains an array named `facilities` the definition of your Code needs to consider this and expect an object that contains an array called `facilities`. At the moment your code expects an Array at root level.

Answer (score 1):

try changing the return type of your get function to Facilities

```
interface FacilityApi {

    @GET("/iranjith4/ad-assignment/db")
    fun getFacilities() : Facilities
}
```